# How to make custom completion Handler with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've looked through various documents, but don't know how to apply the completion handler in the following cases.

```
//example function.
//default textView height 100.0f

-(void)getHeightResult{
  [self initHeight];
  NSLog(@"%@", [self setTextManager]);
}

-(NSString *)setTextManager{
   if(self.textView.frame.size.heigh != 100){
      return @"new Height";
   } else{
      return @"Default Height;
   }
}

-(void)initHeight{
   int result;
   for(int i = 0 ; i <= 20: i ++){
     result = result + i;
   }
   //result = 210
   self.textView.frame.size.height = result;
}
```

When executing the above functions, getHeightResult always outputs 'Default Height'.
How can I apply a Completion Handler to get it returned as the value calculated in initHeight from a source like this?

We ask for answers to help you understand the Completion Handler, not for asking the actual source.

Comment: You should avoid the term `init` at the start of methods unless that method is an Objective-C class initializer.

Comment: thanks your advice.

Comment: `initHeight` isn't asynchronous.  There is no point to a completion block.  When the method returns, it has been executed in its entirety already.   You have a different bug.   Most likely `textView` is `nil`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Code for completionHandler,

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self getSize:^(bool status) {
        if (status == true) {
            // perofm your operioan
            NSLog(@"Done");
        }
    }];
}

typedef void (^CompletionBlock)(_Bool status);

-(void)getSize:(CompletionBlock)block{
    __block int count = 0;

    [self initWidth:^(bool status) {
        count++;
        if (count == 2) {
            block(true);
        }
    }];

    [self initHeight:^(bool status) {
        count++;
        if (count == 2) {
            block(true);
        }
    }];
}


-(void)initHeight:(CompletionBlock)block{
    int result;
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= 100; i ++) {
        result = result + i;
    }
    block(true);
}

-(void)initWidth:(CompletionBlock)block{
    int result;
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= 20; i ++){
        result = result + i;
    }
    block(true);
}
```

Comment: What if getHeightResult tells me that two functions are completed instead of one?

Comment: can you please explain in details, what do you mean by two function? you are talking about initHeight and setTextManager methods ?

Comment: There is no point to a completion block as there is nothing in `initHeight:` that is executing asynchronously.

Comment: There is a separate initWidth and function like initHeight. When we call these two functions in a function called getSize, we want to know that both initHeight and initWidth are completed using the completion handler for the function getSize. SGDev Your answer has helped me a lot in understanding the completion handler.

Comment: @프로꾸 check my updated code, it is only for your understanding purpose, Please make changes according to your requirement.

Comment: @프로꾸 This isn't really a completion handler;  there is no asynchronous execution and there is no demonstrated "which queue gets the completion" policy.   This is nothing more than a very weird way of executing code in a single threaded fashion.

Comment: just simple example